# How to updated UI from thread?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, database-performance, query-performance

I was facing some problem in using thread in android app .

I have Activity1.java which have some function which get data from sql lite database and displaying it on the activity . I have one method Load() which fill some spinner static and some from database . Second spinner values is depend on first drop down , so on. It also visible / invisible some UI controls

Scenario 1 :-

If we call Load() function on oncreate() Method , then activity will go slow down .

Scenario 2 :- (Thread)

If we call Load() function inside thread on oncreate() Method and i use runOnUiThread or Handler.post to update the ui controls , then it will skip that code , go further in code and my other values are some wrong or not properly come .

Scenario 3 :- (Async)

If we call Load() function inside Aysnc on oncreate() Method , then i have to update ui continuously from async task . Updation in UI is only allowed on onPostExecute(Result) and onProgressUpdate(Progress...) , but how i update ui continuously  from async .

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           BindStaticValues();
    GetCalculationOptions();
}
 public void BindStaticValues()
{

    //standard 
    BindStandard(); //static spinner (not db)           

    //Spinner 1
    array1 = new ArrayList<ObjectMaterial>();
    Adapter1 = new DescriptionAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            array1 );
    Adapter1 
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(Adapter1 );

    //Spinner 2
    array2 = new ArrayList<ObjectMaterial>();
    Adapter2 = new DescriptionAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            array2 );
    Adapter2 
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sp2.setAdapter(Adapter2 );

}


public void GetCalculationOptions ()
{

    progressCalcualtionOptions = ProgressDialog.show(context, getString(R.string.progressCalcualtionOptionsTitle),
            getString(R.string.progressCalcualtionOptionsMessage), true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try 
            {
                LoadValuesforFirstTime(false, false, false); //main load method (Need Updating UI)
                isFirstOpen=false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {   
                //Log.d(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (progressCalcualtionOptions != null)
            {
                progressCalcualtionOptions.dismiss();
                progressCalcualtionOptions=null;
            }       


        }
    }).start();

}


private void LoadValuesforFirstTime(Boolean FromMaterial,
        Boolean FromLangugae, Boolean FromCountry) {


    ChangeVisibility(); // it will change visibility of some controls 

    FillSpinner1(TypeofMaterial); //fill first spinner 1

    FillSpinner2(ObjectMaterial); //fill first spinner 2 (take values from spinner 1 or manipulate values in spinner 1)

}

private void ChangeVisibility() {

// it will change visibility of some controls 

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


            relat_heightPipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relat_PipeDiameter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relat_WidthPipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relat_length.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            relat_lblMediumHeatCapacity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relat_lblMediumDensity.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
}

private void FillSpinner1(String TypeofMaterial) {

          array1 = DB_Manager.All(); //get from db

    h.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Adapter1.clear();
                for (ObjectMaterial object : array1 )
                    Adapter1.add(object);   

                Adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}

       private void FillSpinner2(String TypeofMaterial) {


          array2 = DB_Manager.All1(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition()); //get from db

    h.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Adapter2.clear();
                for (ObjectMaterial object : array2 )
                    Adapter2.add(object);   

                Adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
}
```

Now , Problem is :-

When activity open , GetCalculationOptions call a thread to fill all spinner values. In this it call LoadValuesforFirstTime() function.Here i do all things with db and ui .
Here changevisibility change visibility of some controls , FillSpinner1 fill get values from db , refresh adapter inside main ui thread , fill Spinenr2 get values from db according to selected values in spinner 1 , but there no values will find in spinner1 because it is not filled till now and it is an another thread , now point we have to update UI continuously from LoadValuesforFirstTime() functions.

Anyone , plz help me or suggest me any other option for achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

call your method in

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

                  write your method here 

        }
     });
```

from `doInbackground` method.

Comment: If i run all function on main ui thread , then activity go slow .

Comment: just call that method in run method which is responsible to update ui .